# deployed the jars on tomcat and remane old jars but server still reading old jars

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have modified some jars and deployed on tomcat.Due to policy of company i can not remove the old jars so i rename the jars like "myApp" to "myApp-bkp-12-2-21". But server still reading the old jars

What should be the solution of this?

Comment: move this to a differnt location other than your workspace

Comment: do you try to reatart tomcat server?

Comment: Yeah I have restart the server and also delete the work folder from tomcat, but still same issue

Comment: is it maven based... check and delete from maven too

Comment: In my previous Organization we used to append .bac ext to the jar/build/back-up names.
and moving to different location is always a good idea.

Comment: @spandey Thanks :) This solved my issue

Comment: @UbaidUllahCRM good to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat always assumes that *all* jars in specific directories (e.g. WEB-INF/lib) are on the classpath - no matter how elaborated your renaming is. Personally, I wouldn't even trust renaming a `.jar` file to `.something-other-than-jar`. So: Don't keep old crufty jars around. Delete them! Have the company policy changed.

A company policy that doesn't allow developers to delete old and obsolete code, or to overwrite it, sounds as if it's the wrong environment to develop software in. It's your job to update/add/remove new files and deploy new code. I'd question if that policy is interpreted correctly here.

Comment: Thank you ! Deleting the old jars from Web-inf/lib and replacing new solved my issue..I just take backup in other folder.

Comment: We are working for a Banking Products, So bank policy doesn't allow us to delete anything due to their Audit\